# How to change price for all products in magento

Tags: price, products, backend, magento-1.9.2.1, associate-products

we are trishlaemart.com we do have some products for example

existing product JulietBra = price is 10o$ 
                             associate products is 120$

need to change price now for all product as 120$ in single shot how to do it ? any easy way is there or i need to do each and every product. manually

same wise one product is 10$ i need to change all price to 20$ includes associate products.

Comment: You can import the product CSV to update the product price.

Comment: As @DineshYadav suggested you can use default Magento's import option. Please let us know if you need any help in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Export the csv and use magmi tool to update price in bulk. Below should be the format of csv:

```
store, sku, price

abc, 1001, 5.00

bab, 1001, 7.00
```

then run re-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You run below script into magento root directory

***Note:Firstly take backup of DB then execute this query***

**For All products**

```
$storeId=Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); // Your store id

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// For all products
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addStoreFilter();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $price=$product->setPrice(120);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
    $product->save(); 
}
?>
```

**For specific products:**

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$storeId=Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); // Your store id

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$productIds = array(1,2,3,4,5); // pass products id

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addStoreFilter();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $price=$product->setPrice(120);
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
    $product->save(); 
}
?>
```